# MVC2 ViewModel Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

How do I get properties in my BLL passed down to a ModeView.  For example, I have this class in a separate Class Library:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetaData))]
public partial class Person
{        
    [Bind(Include = "PersonId,DepartmentId,FirstName,LastName,Active,DateAdded,DateDeleted")]
    public class PersonMetaData
    {           
        public object PersonId { get; set; }

        public object DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public object FirstName { get; set; }

        public object LastName { get; set; }

        public Department PersonDepartment { get; set; }

        public string FullName()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FullName{ get; set; }
    public string PersonDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate a new "View" strongly-typed to the PersonViewModel and set as "List" View Content....the page is generated, but FullName is not coming through.

I created the PersonDepartment property because I want to display the Department Name the person is in.  I have a Department Class set up similarly.  For example, I want to be able to do something like "PersonDepartment.DepartmentName" that displays the department name on the page.

I am using a DBML (Linq To SQL), so the partial classes are extending from the auto-generated classes.

I am not sure how to get FullName property filled and passed to ViewModel and get Department properties connected to the Person information being passed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am assuming of course that you are populating the view model before you pass it to the view, yes?

Comment: Sorry - yes.  ViewModel is being populated using the AutoMapper dll.  Mapping is working because PersonId property is in fact getting passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that you are using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). In your model `FullName` is a method and not a property. AutoMapper won't map automatically to methods. According to the [conventions](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/01/22/automapper-the-object-object-mapper.aspx) you could prefix your method name with `Get` to make this to work:

```
public string GetFullName()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

This will be mapped to the `FullName` property in the view model. Another option is to explicitly declare how the mapping is done:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>()
      .ForMember(
          dest => dest.FullName, 
          opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FullName())
      );
```

As far as the department name property is concerned I would recommend you modify your model so that instead of a `DepartmentId` property it has directly a property called `Department` containing the id and the name which will allow you to map them easily in your view model. If you cannot modify your model this way you could have the `Department` property in the view model populated directly by the repository and not by `AutoMapper`.